# RealTek 8101E ethernet card or similar doesn't work on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, freebsd, drivers

I'm trying to install FreeBSD on my netbook using an usb sitck but I'm running into a major problem, my ethernet card doesn't work.

```
ifconfig -a
```

only returns me

```
lo0 …
```

but

```
dmesg | grep re0
```

gives me:

```
re0: <RealTek 8101E/8102E/8102EL/8103E PCIe 10/100baseTX> ...
re0: Using 1 MSI messages
re0: Chip rev. 0x24000000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
re0: Unknown H/W revision rev. 0x24000000
device_attach: re0 attach returned 6
```

The installer crashes when I try to setup the network on FreeBSD 8.1 amd64 or 8.2RC3 amd64 on usb stick. Same dmesg messages with 9.0 CURRENT but it doesn't crash nor find re0.

The network works fine with NetBSD 5.1 amd64 or OpenBSD 4.8 i386 using re.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may not be supported. That is, I believe, what these messages are saying:

```
re0: Unknown H/W revision rev. 0x24000000
device_attach: re0 attach returned 6
```

There are other messages that discuss other hardware revisions that are also not recognized (check this [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=freebsd+re0%3a+device+attach+returned+6)). The release notes for 8.0 have a section on [Ethernet cards](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/8.0R/hardware.html#ETHERNET); see if your card is actually supported there.